# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build TextField

Tags: android, flutter, widget, textfield

I'm calling a homemade EnterTextField with a TextField. But when this screen is opened, the following errors are shown. And the input field loses focus (if you click on the numbers on the keyboard, nothing happens), until you set the focus in the text field yourself (tap on the TextField).

Call from widget:

```
return TextField(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(context,
      PageRouteBuilder(
        opaque: false,
        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => EnterTextField(
          controller: textController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  readOnly: true,
  inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
  controller: textController,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
);
```

Widget with TextField on

```
Widget _numberTextField(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
          keyboardType: keyboardType,
          autofocus: true,
          onSubmitted: (_) {
            context.goBack();
          },
          onChanged: (string) {

          },
          controller: controller,
          inputFormatters: inputFormatted != null ? [inputFormatted!] : [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
          scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
    );
  }
```

Exception:

```
======== Exception caught by foundation library ====================================================
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for TextEditingController:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This EditableText widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: EditableText-[LabeledGlobalKey<EditableTextState>#0bea4]
 controller: TextEditingController#2bf2b(TextEditingValue(text: ┤25├, selection: TextSelection.invalid, composing: TextRange(start: -1, end: -1)))
 focusNode: FocusNode#6314d
 debugLabel: ((englishLike titleMedium 2014).merge((blackMountainView titleMedium).apply)).merge(unknown)
 inherit: false
 color: Color(0xff000000)
 family: SFProDisplay
 size: 18.0
 weight: 400
 baseline: alphabetic
 decoration: TextDecoration.none
 textAlign: start
 autofocus: true
 keyboardType: TextInputType(name: TextInputType.number, signed: false, decimal: false)
 autofillHints: []
 dependencies: [ScrollConfiguration, Directionality, _FocusMarker, MediaQuery, _EffectiveTickerMode]
 state: EditableTextState#8aaa7(tickers: tracking 1 ticker)
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: AddInfoProductPage
 dirty
 dependencies: [MediaQuery]
 state: _AddInfoProductPageState#c08be
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4424:11)
#1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4439:6)
#2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1141:15)
#3      EditableTextState._didChangeTextEditingValue (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:2640:5)
#4      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:308:24)
#5      ValueNotifier.value= (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:412:5)
#6      TextEditingController.value= (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:154:11)
#7      TextEditingController.text= (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:139:5)
#8      _AddInfoProductPageState._serialTextField (package:aliusadmin/presentation/pages/AddInfoProductPage.dart:174:20)
#9      _AddInfoProductPageState._addInfo (package:aliusadmin/presentation/pages/AddInfoProductPage.dart:127:46)
#10     _AddInfoProductPageState.view (package:aliusadmin/presentation/pages/AddInfoProductPage.dart:74:21)
#11     _AddInfoProductPageState.build (package:aliusadmin/presentation/pages/AddInfoProductPage.dart:48:12)
#12     StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4870:27)
#13     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4754:15)
#14     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#15     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#16     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#17     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#18     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#19     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#20     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#21     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:995:5)
#25     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#26     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#27     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
The TextEditingController sending notification was: TextEditingController#2bf2b(TextEditingValue(text: ┤25├, selection: TextSelection.invalid, composing: TextRange(start: -1, end: -1)))


  ======== Exception caught by foundation library ====================================================
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for TextEditingController:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This AnimatedBuilder widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: AnimatedBuilder
 animation: Listenable.merge([FocusNode#6314d(context: Focus, NOT FOCUSABLE), TextEditingController#2bf2b(TextEditingValue(text: ┤25├, selection: TextSelection.invalid, composing: TextRange(start: -1, end: -1)))])
 state: _AnimatedState#1af83
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: AddInfoProductPage
 dirty
 dependencies: [MediaQuery]
 state: _AddInfoProductPageState#c08be
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4424:11)
#1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4439:6)
#2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1141:15)
#3      _AnimatedState._handleChange (package:flutter/src/widgets/transitions.dart:128:5)
#4      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:308:24)
#5      ValueNotifier.value= (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:412:5)
#6      TextEditingController.value= (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:154:11)
#7      TextEditingController.text= (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:139:5)
#8      _AddInfoProductPageState._serialTextField (package:aliusadmin/presentation/pages/AddInfoProductPage.dart:174:20)
#9      _AddInfoProductPageState._addInfo (package:aliusadmin/presentation/pages/AddInfoProductPage.dart:127:46)
#10     _AddInfoProductPageState.view (package:aliusadmin/presentation/pages/AddInfoProductPage.dart:74:21)
#11     _AddInfoProductPageState.build (package:aliusadmin/presentation/pages/AddInfoProductPage.dart:48:12)
#12     StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4870:27)
#13     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4754:15)
#14     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#15     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#16     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#17     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#18     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#19     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#20     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#21     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:995:5)
#25     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#26     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#27     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
The TextEditingController sending notification was: TextEditingController#2bf2b(TextEditingValue(text: ┤25├, selection: TextSelection.invalid, composing: TextRange(start: -1, end: -1)))
```

**What could cause this exception?**

Answer (score 1):

There should be a StatefulWidget involved here to get that error. Look up addPostFrameCallback, that's almost certainly what you'll need. It goes in the initState of the StatefulWidget.

In short, a function is trying to execute before the build() has finished. The way to delay its execution is with addPostFrameCallback. This ensures the method won't be called after the build method has finished.